# Repeat CSS background at certain position

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to get a background tile for a certain position, like so:

[image: mock up]

I have the following CSS and dummy div under the body tag.

```
div#dummy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64....");      
}
```

However this doesn't reach the bottom despite specifying bottom 0. Any ideas? I think I may be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: It seems to be working fine(no white bar on the bottom) in FF 3.6.23 on Fedora, also works for me with Andy1986 s solution.  Did you verify this issue in other browsers? Maybe a body style with margin applied to it?

Comment: The bottom part appears to be blue (ie the background used in the body). I do use a reset and this is the same in FF7 and Chrome 15. Still testing the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure you are including a reset.css http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

You can then try setting the `background` property of the body itself, setting the position like so:

```
background: blue url('myimage.png') no-repeat left bottom;
```

The "blue" at the start specifies the colour of the top  part of the image. The two properties at the end specify the background "position". Specifying bottom should make it glue to the bottom.

Then the height of the background image itself will determine how far up the tile it comes. You can use `repeat-x` instead of `no-repeat` if you want the background to tile horizontally..

One of many ways no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

it should work-

```
html, body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
} 
#bluePart
{
    height:30%;
    width:100%;
    background:#2A3BA6;
    border:solid 0px #000000;
}
#lowerTilePart
{
    height:70%;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(images/bgImage.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border:solid 0px #FF0000;
}
```

the css style for **html, body** part is must.